# My class derived from RouteSubscriberBase is not used

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I would like to override the user login form in order to replace the username field with an email field.

I created a module (with EventSubscriber declared as service) and installed it. However, my class is not used load when I try to access to the user/login route. The call to `exit()` I use in my code doesn't display anything.

```
  /**
   * @file
   * Contains \Drupal\override_user\Routing\RouteSubscriber
   */

   namespace Drupal\override_user\Routing;

   use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
   use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

   /**
    * Listens to the dynamic route events.
    */
      class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
         exit('user/login access');
         $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\override_user\Form\MyUserLoginForm');
     }
    }
  }
```

#### My service

```
    services:
    route_subscriber:
        class: Drupal\override_user\Routing\RouteSubscriber
        tags: 
             - {name: event_subscriber }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What you do is what is also described in https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643. You should use override_user.route_subscriber, since the service name needs to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modifed my service like that : override_user.route_subscriber:

Comment: Did that help, or are you still having the same problem?

Comment: Sorry, didn't finish my answer... I modifed my service like that :   override_user.route_subscriber. But nohing has changed. I don't have my exit

Comment: Do my module needs dependencies ? (in override_user.info.yml)

Comment: You don't need dependencies, but you should need to uninstall and re-install the module; editing the code of an installed module is not allowing Drupal to notice changes. Also, instead of using `exit()` you should check the form is really changed, or use Drupal logger (the equivalent to the old `watchdog()`.

Comment: Ok. I deleted the module and re-installed it. But my form didn't change. I'm looking for hours and I don't know why my alterRouting doesn't works...